# Position doesn't work for custom symbol within package

Tags: packages, symbols, searching

In a notebook, I can easily search an expression for a custom symbol.

```
In[237]:= Position[{mySym, 1, 2}, mySym]
Out[237]= {{1}}
```

However, if I write a function and place it within a package;

```
FindSym[x_] := Position[x, mySym]

In[234]:= Clear@"PA`"
<< PA`
PA`Private`FindSym[{mySym, 1, 2}]
Out[236]= {}
```

The symbol can no longer be found. However, if instead of searching on a symbol, I search on a literal (string or number) or even a built-in name, the package version works.

I feel I'm missing something subtle. If anybody could give me pointers, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you literally have

```
FindSym[x_] := Position[x, mySym]
```

in your package, then *this* `mySym` is probably created in `` PA`Private` ``  (depending on your package setup). `` PA`Private`mySym ``  is distinct from `` Global`mySym `` . You were searching for the former when only the latter was present.

Comment: Doh! I felt it was something like that. Thank you Szabolcs.